# Add several copies of the same imported model in a scene in THREE.Js

Tags: three.js, duplicates, gltf

I've imported a 3D model into a THREE.Js project I've been working on, and I want to add several copies of them to the scene. Here's the code I've been using to duplicate it:

```
let ball = new THREE.Mesh();
loader.load( './ball.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(model) { //for gltf shadows!
        if (model.isMesh) {
          model.castShadow = true;
          model.material = sphereMaterial;
        }
    });
    ball = gltf.scene;
    scene.add( ball );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );

const ball2 = ball.clone()
ball2.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
scene.add(ball2)
```

However, only one of the "balls" show up in the scene from the `loader.load()` call. Does anyone happen to know what I should do differently to successfully duplicate the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onLoad()` handler (`function ( gltf ) {...}`) is asynchronous, and the code that clones `ball` (`const ball2 = ball.clone()`) is executing before `ball` is initialized with the GLTF data.  So at the time `ball.clone()` executes, `ball` is simply the empty `Mesh` you created before loading the GLTF, and that empty `Mesh` is what gets cloned.

I suspect you were, at some point, getting a console error relating to reading `clone` on undefined, and that's why you added the line to initialize `ball` to an empty `Mesh`, which is unnecessary.

There are a few ways to handle this, but the simplest is to move the code that clones `ball` into the `onLoad` handler (*i.e.*, after `scene.add( ball )`).

Proof of concept [here](https://codepen.io/pnichols04/pen/wvpEBVx).